# Confused about ranged for loops

Tags: c++, ranged-loops

To me, this doesn't produce the expected results:

```
int main() {

    int i[12] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    for (auto v : i)
        std::cout << v << std::endl;

    for (auto v : i)
        v = v+1;

    for (auto v : i)
        std::cout << v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The second `for` loop doesn't seem to do anything. Are range-based `for` loops read-only, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second loop, `auto v : i`, `v` is a *copy* of each `i`.

To change the `i` values, you need a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)):

```
int main() {
  int i[12] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

  for (auto v : i)
    std::cout << v << std::endl;

  for (auto& v : i)  // Add "&" here. Now each v is a reference of i.
    v = v + 1;

  for (auto v : i)
    std::cout << v << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/DVQllH.

Comment: @RikardRasmussen Would you mind accepting the answer if it helps?

Comment: Of course! It tells me I have 6 minutes left to wait though.